# WooCommerce Custom Single Product Template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good morning, I'm trying to change the header depending on the category of the single product. i am using Wordpress & WooCommerce
My product categories look like this

```
- the-lawn-store
- - turf
- - grass-seed
- - wildflower-turf

- the-oak-store
- - railway-sleepers
- - pergolas
```

Basically when viewing an item which falls under the parent category of the-lawn-store I need the header to be `<?php get_header('lawn'); ?>` and when the parent category is the-oak-store I need the header to be `<?php get_header('oak'); ?>`, the difference between headers is the styling of the over all page! what is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you need is the category parent. In order to do that, first of all you can get the parent ID with this:

```
    global $wp_query;

$cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

if($cat_obj)    {
    //print_r($cat_obj);
    $category_ID = $cat_obj->term_id;
    $category_parent = $cat_obj->parent;
    $category_taxonomy = $cat_obj->taxonomy;

    $category_parent_term = get_term_by( 'id', absint( $category_ID ), $category_taxonomy );
    $category_parent_slug = $category_parent_term->slug;

    get_header( $category_parent_slug ); 

}else{

    get_header();

    }
```

Uncomment the print_r to see the rest of available vars. Tested on my local woo and works.

Answer (score 1):

You can't filter the `get_header()` function so you will have to override WooCommerce's `single-product.php` template. From there you can modify the beginning of the file:

```
 get_header( 'shop' ); ?>
```

I created the following function to get the top-level product category for any product:

```
function kia_get_the_top_level_product_category( $post_id = null ){

    $product_cat_parent = null;

    if( ! $post_id ){ 
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    } 

    // get the product's categories
    $product_categories = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );

    if( is_array( $product_categories ) ) {
        // gets complicated if multiple categories, so limit to one
        // on the backend you can restrict to a single category with my Radio Buttons for Taxonomies plugin
        $product_cat = array_shift( $product_categories);
        $product_cat_id = $product_cat->term_id;

        while ($product_cat_id) {
            $cat = get_term($product_cat_id, 'product_cat'); // get the object for the product_cat_id
            $product_cat_id = $cat->parent; // assign parent ID (if exists) to $product_cat_id
            // the while loop will continue whilst there is a $product_cat_id
            // when there is no longer a parent $product_cat_id will be NULL so we can assign our $product_cat_parent
            $product_cat_parent = $cat->slug;
        }

    }

    return $product_cat_parent;

}
```

Then in your theme's `single-product.php` you could do:

```
$parent = kia_get_the_top_level_product_category();
if( $parent == 'oak' ){
   get_header('oak');
} elseif( $parent == 'lawn' ){
   get_header('lawn');
} else {
   get_header('shop');
}
```

If you don't have a specific `header-shop.php` then you could technically also do:

```
$parent = kia_get_the_top_level_product_category();
get_header( $parent );
```

Overriding this template might put you at risk when WooCommerce upgrades. As an alternative I would suggest filtering the body class.

```
function wpa_22066003_body_class($c){
    if( function_exists('is_product') && is_product() && $parent = kia_get_the_top_level_product_category() ){
        $c[] = $parent . '-product-category';
    }
    return $c;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpa_22066003_body_class' );
```